# Missing images in an image collection creating errors when trying to calculate daily surfaces through ee.List.sequence function

Tags: google-earth-engine

A MAIAC image collection has multiple images for a single day; however, it also has some days without any effective measurement for a region. I wanted to generate daily surfaces through a mean function, but found that using `ee.List.sequence` will incur errors in days when there was no effective measurement.

How can I work around days where there are no measurements?

```
var startDate2016 = ee.Date('2016-01-01'); //missing data for 2/18-2/25
var endDate2016 = ee.Date('2016-03-01');

var maiac_aod_cal2016 = maiac_aod //the GEE asset name
  .filterDate(startDate2016, endDate2016) //endDate does not include data for the last date
  .select('Optical_Depth_047');
//print(maiac_aod_cal.size());

// use image.map function to clip the image collection
var maiac_aod_cal2016v2 = maiac_aod_cal2016.map(function(image) { 
  return image.clip(cal10kmbuff); 
});

//maintain the projection
var  maiac_aod_prj = function(image) {
  var im = image.select(0);
  return image.reproject({
    crs: maiac_aod_cal2016.first().projection(),
    scale: 1000})};

//calculate daily means because one day might have multiple measurements
var num_days2016 = endDate2016.difference(startDate2016, 'days');
var days2016 = ee.List.sequence(1, num_days2016); //this creates number of days but some days no AOD data

var daily_aod2016 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      days2016.map(function (day) {
          var aod_day2016 = maiac_aod_cal2016v2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(day, day, 'day_of_year'));
          //the following line of code does not work
          if ( ee.Filter.greaterThan(aod_day2016.size(), 0) ) {
              return aod_day2016.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['Optical_Depth_047']))
                    .mean()
                    .set({'day_of_year': day,
                        'system:time_start': aod_day2016.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(), 
                               ['system:time_start']).get('min')
                        //Error in map(ID=00000000000000000051): Image.date: Image '48' does not have a 
                        // 'system:time_start' property.
                    });
          } 
}));
var maiac_aod_cal2016v22 = daily_aod2016.map(maiac_aod_prj);
```

Comment: Does your script not run if you just use the code within your `if` statement? I would think that Earth Engine would return a empty image if `aod_day2016` has a size of zero. `daily_aod2016` would then have the same size as `days2016`. If desired, empty images could be removed by filtering `daily_aod2016` using `.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['system:time_start']))`, since `aod_day2016` would have no `system:time_start` property if empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an image sequence with different multiple images for a single day (inclusively, it also has some days without any effective images) it is preferable to use distinct dates sequence for searching frequencies of these dates in complete dates list. With the frequencies thus calculated, it can be perfectly sliced original list of Images for calculating mean of each image slices (there are slices with 2, 4 and 5 images and 8 days without images).

In your code, you don't define **cal10kmbuff** area so, I assumed an arbitrary geometry with this name. On the other hand, I used an Image Collection for MAIAC data filtered with your same dates range and 'Optical_Depth_047' band. Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0dfcf7150562f1d4ea4a4dbe17472cc2) look as follows:

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([-103.8331184737015, 36.02709782490108]);

var cal10kmbuff = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-103.85921100299838, 36.041534742284675],
          [-103.85921100299838, 36.009881119019475],
          [-103.80977252643588, 36.009881119019475],
          [-103.80977252643588, 36.041534742284675]]], null, false);

Map.addLayer(cal10kmbuff);
Map.addLayer(pt);
Map.centerObject(cal10kmbuff);

var startDate2016 = ee.Date('2016-01-01'); //missing data for 2/18-2/25
var endDate2016 = ee.Date('2016-03-01');

var maiac_aod_cal2016 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
                  .select('Optical_Depth_047')
                  .filterDate(startDate2016, endDate2016)
                  .filterBounds(pt);

print("Image Collection", maiac_aod_cal2016);

var diff = endDate2016.difference(startDate2016, 'days');

print("Days between dates", diff);

var allDates = ee.List(maiac_aod_cal2016.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple1 = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

//print(allDatesSimple1);

var allDatesSimple2 = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  }).distinct();

print("All Distinct dates", allDatesSimple2);

var freq = allDatesSimple2.map(function detFreq (ele) {
  
  var idx = ee.Number(allDatesSimple2.indexOf(ele));
  
  var freq = allDatesSimple1.frequency(allDatesSimple2.get(idx));
  
  return freq;
  
});

print("Frequences of dates", freq);

var freq_accum = ee.Array(freq).accum(0);

print("Accumulate frequences of dates", freq_accum);

var listOfImages = maiac_aod_cal2016.toList(maiac_aod_cal2016.size());

var n = ee.Number(freq_accum.toList().size());

var list_idx_start = freq_accum.toList().insert(0,0).slice(0, n);
var list_idx_end = freq_accum.toList();

var indices = list_idx_start.zip(list_idx_end);

print("Indices for slicing list of Images", indices);

var daily_aod2016_mean = indices.map(function selectImages(ele){
  
  var time = ee.Date(allDatesSimple2.get(indices.indexOf(ele)));
  
  var start = ee.List(ele).get(0);
  var end = ee.List(ele).get(1);
  
  var img = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listOfImages.slice(start, end)).mean();
  
  return img.set('system:time_start', time);
  
});

print("Mean of Daily Images", daily_aod2016_mean);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following image. It can be observed that each one of 52 produced images (not 60 as it was inferred in your code because there are 8 days without any images) has 'Optical_Depth_047' band with its respective 'system:time_start'.

[image]